# How can I get Google Earth working?

Tags: 10.10, installation, google-earth

I would like to install Google Earth under Ubuntu 10.10. Under v10.04 there were some problems. Has anyone been able to get it working satisfactorily? Was Wine used?

Comment: I can't think of any reason to want to use WINE when Google specifically produces a Linux native binary (which has always worked just fine for me). Do other OpenGL programs work properly on your system? `glxgears` is always a good sanity check for your GL installation.

Comment: Have you considered KDE's Marble instead?

Comment: Eh...Marble's not really very featureful.  Can't look store locations or look for exact places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I am answering my own question here.
Google earth didn't play very nice on v10.04, but there at least was a mediubuntu package for that version. There isn't a v10.10 package available.

So to get GoogleEarth working, you will need to add something to the software sources.

```
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free
```

After doing that click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/googleearth) to automatically install this package.

I tried many things, and this was the option that actually worked. GoogleEarth looks great now!

Answer (score 8):

Here are some methods to install google earth :

Method 1: Medibuntu
Medibuntu offers a Google Earth package for Ubuntu 10.04. You can download and install it here. Scroll to the bottom of the page and select your system type (i386/32 bit, amd64/64 bit) to start the download. Double-click on the downloaded package to open the Package Installer, and click Install Package.

Start Google Earth from Applications->Internet->Google Earth.

Method 2: googleearth-package
If the Medibuntu package is out of date or unavailable, you can create your own package with an easy script. The Ubuntu repositories offer a script which can create an easy to install Google Earth package for you.

Open Ubuntu Software Center and install googleearth-package.
Open Applications->Accessories->Terminal
Type the command:
make-googleearth-package --force
Wait for the script to build your package. This could take a minute or two depending on the speed of your computer and your Internet connection. At the end you should see:
Success!
You can now install the package with e.g. sudo dpkg -i .deb
You should now have a Google Earth package waiting in your home folder. Open Places->Home Folder, find the package named googleearth_VERSION_ARCH.deb, double-click to open the Package Installer, and click Install Package.
Start Google Earth from Applications->Internet->Google Earth.
If you’re having trouble, check out the Ubuntu Community Documentation on Google Earth. I’ve also written previously about installing Google Earth using the installer from Google.

Adapted from [Google Earth Installation](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2010/05/02/how-to-install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-10-04/)

Comment: At the Wine app database stated that , emulating / running Windows Google Earth using Wine for version 4.3.x is Silver ranking while version 5.1 is bronze ranking .

Answer (score 3):

Use this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth

Answer (score 1):

5.2 (the one pulled in by the package and the default download on Google's site) is broken on a lot of hardware.  If that's the problem you're having, 5.1 works fine. Choose 5.1 from "advanced setup" on this page:  http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html

Comment: Exactly like this. 5.2 doesn't work for me on 10.04 and ATI HD2400/radeon, 5.1 works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could install it directly from Google's own repository.  Instructions on setting up that repository for 10.04 are here: http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/ubuntu1004.html

Comment: pretty much what I had to do to get the package working.